# How could Ronan the Accuser be killed by the Power Stone if he is immortal?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, you see the titular Guardians kill Ronan the Accuser on Xandar using the Power Stone. But if he's an immortal entity, shouldn't that mean it can't phase him?

Comment: *Is* Ronan the Accuser immortal? I don't recall that ever being said.

Comment: I do not believe he is immortal.

Comment: [This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/39032/46980) also refers to Ronan as "an immortal entity", so it's possible we're wrong and he is. Even so, immortal =/= invulnerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ronan is not immortal. As seen on this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser) page, his powers are listed as:

> **Abilities**
>
> - Expert in military tactics
> - Skilled hand-to-hand combatant
> - Superhuman strength, speed, endurance, and reflexes
> - Utilizes Kree exoskeleton armor
> - Wields "Universal Weapon"

It mentions nothing about immortality, nor does the page for the Kree. However, it is possible that he became "immortal" at some point, but see this [Q&A](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39032/how-did-ronan-the-accuser-become-so-powerful) to get some clarification on how he became powerful and why you might think he is "immortal".

> When you say;
>
> The Terrans defeated the Kree
>
> I presume that you are talking about in the comics. The comic
>   continuity is not relevant to the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which
>   takes place in an alternate dimension (Earth-199999). As such, the
>   Kree may be very different in the films from in the comics. We have
>   only seen a couple of instances of Kree in the Marvel Cinematic
>   Universe so far, so we don't have that much information to draw upon,
>   but;
>
> We know that in Guardians of the Galaxy, a truce has been drawn up
>   between the Kree and the Xandarians, which implies that they were at
>   war before. The fact that the Xandarians (who are not immortal, as we
>   see many of them die in Guardians of the Galaxy) have been able to
>   negotiate a truce with the Kree suggest that the Kree are not immortal
>   either.
>
> Also in Guardians of the Galaxy, we see that Ronan is able to hold the
>   Power Gem (one of the six Infinity Stones) for a limited amount of
>   time, before embedding it in his hammer. The fact he has to put it in
>   his hammer implies to me that, like the slave girl that works for The
>   Collector, it would have quickly destroyed him. He is also capable of
>   great feats of strength, throwing Drax around like it's no big deal
>   when they fight in Knowhere. So we can see from this that Ronan, if
>   not neccessarily all Kree, are stronger than they might appear.
>
> Additionally, in the Agents of SHIELD season 2 episode "Who You Really
>   Are", we see Lady Sif (an Asgardian) fight a Kree warrior, and the two
>   of them seem to be fairly well matched in terms of strength and
>   durability. This would imply that it isn't just Ronan the Accuser who
>   is strong, it is all Kree (or at least the ones trained in combat).
>
> In short, the Kree are not immortal, but they are very strong, most
>   likely due to their biology rather than any gained power.